# Should I use NSAsynchronousFetchRequest instead of NSFetchRequest all the time?

Tags: core-data

As I understand it, `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` is a wrapper around a standard `NSFetchRequest`, and provides asynchronous execution in a background thread, cancellation and progress report plus the added bonus that during execution, the context is not blocked.

Am I missing something and are there any cases where using "plain" `NSFetchRequests` would still be recommended over using `NSAsynchronousFetchRequests` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a core data stack already setup for background data loading, with a main thread context, where most work is in the background and your UI fetches are pretty simple then there is no need to use an async fetch.

If you're setting up a new stack and you know that your UI fetch processing is going to be complex, because you need to fetch and post process lots of data for each request, then async fetches could help.

It really depends on what you're doing, there is no single rule. If a UI fetch is causing you performance problems then it's a candidate for switching to async to avoid that problem. If you can run a fetch while the user is actively doing something else with the UI that's also a good candidate. But, if the user is waiting for the result of a simple fetch then that probably isn't worth it...

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` makes only sense in a UI context, because the main feature is not to block the active thread after firing. This is only useful in the main thread.

However, in a lot of tests I have performed `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` turns out to be a little bit slower than `NSFetchRequest`. This means that `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` is in most cases not a smart choice for fetching the main data in a view. The user has no benefit of the non-blocked UI when there is nothing to view at and when the waiting time is even longer.

But for fetching less important data in your UI, like badges or status info, a `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` may be useful if these fetches would otherwise block the UI.